# WGET can't resolve host

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian, wget, resolve

I've got 2 machines on the same sub-net running Debian 5.0.  They use the same DNS (/etc/resolv.conf), they route to the same gateway (#route) and they have the same iptables settings (#iptables -L).  I can ping from both of them, both to IP addresses and to host names.  I can run #host www.google.com and get the same results on both of them.  But the problem is that on one of them, I can't wget or curl.

So on machine 1 everything is OK, but on machine 2 (with the same settings as machine 1) I can't wget or curl.

**The error I get is:**

```
# wget google.com
--2009-10-20 16:38:36--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address `google.com'
```

But on machine 1 it has no problem to wget or curl and returns:

```
# wget google.com
--2009-10-20 16:43:55--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com... 74.125.53.100, 74.125.45.100, 74.125.67.100
Connecting to google.com|74.125.53.100|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
...
Saving to: `index.html.3'
```

Etc.

I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction here so that I can possibly fix this issue :)

Comment: This is most probably not related to wget but to a networking issue.

Comment: do you have a proxy setting in the environment .. my work machine did :-(

Comment: Try "host google.com", not "host www.google.com", on server 2.

Answer (score 22):

Check your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file (or whatever the equivalent is on Debian if it's not that).

`host` and `nslookup` *always* do DNS lookups.

However other applications will look in NSS first for other naming systems (e.g. `/etc/hosts`, NIS, etc).  If something else is configured but not working it could prevent the application from ever trying the DNS.

Comment: The canonical way to check the resolver is running `getent hosts google.com`.  This uses nsswitch.conf and then resolv.conf as required.

Answer (score 13):

Thanks for the answers you guys!

It was the nsswitch.conf file.  I had setup LDAP from a tutorial that told me to use this line in hosts:

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

When I changed it to this:

```
hosts: files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
```

It works without a problem.  So I guess the nsswitch config file was making it return null if not found in files or mdns4_minimal, right?

**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: You should probably accept Alnitak's answer.

Comment: Yeah, how do I do that? :-/

Comment: Accept by clicking the "V" next to the vote score. :)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but next to changing `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts: files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4
```

I also had to change the name servers:

Change `/etc/resolv.conf` so it points to the google nameservers. The ones added by network manager don't work for me.

```
# RED 2013-03-31
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Thanks, anonymous, for the constructive comment on the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Could there be an invalid proxy configured on the machine with the error?  Try this:

```
# wget --no-proxy google.com
```

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to try is checking whether DNS works correctly.

```
# host google.com
google.com has address 74.125.67.100
google.com has address 74.125.45.100
google.com has address 74.125.53.100
```

If you don't get that response, check /etc/resolv.conf and find the name servers listed in that file. Can you ping each of them?

Try querying each of them individually:

```
# host google.com 12.34.56.78
```

Can you resolve another host?