# DNS issue? I cannot ping FQDN, yet I can ping alias (CNAME)

Tags: domain-name-system, ping

I'm experencing weird DNS issue and I was wondering if someone has any ideas:

```
# ping -c1 test.XXX.local
ping: unknown host test.XXX.local
# ping -c1 test
PING test.XXX.local (10.52.223.41) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from test.XXX.local (10.52.223.41): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.307 ms

--- test.XXX.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.307/0.307/0.307/0.000 ms
#
```

my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search XXX.local
nameserver 10.52.223.41
nameserver 10.52.223.42
$
```

my `/etc/hosts`:

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
#
```

dig output:

```
# dig test.XXX.local @10.52.223.41

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 <<>> test.XXX.local @10.52.223.41
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 25966
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;test.XXX.local.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
test.XXX.local. 86400   IN  A   10.52.223.41

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
XXX.local.      86400   IN  NS  ns01.XXX.local.
XXX.local.      86400   IN  NS  ns02.XXX.local.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns02.XXX.local. 1200    IN  A   10.52.223.42

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.52.223.41#53(10.52.223.41)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 18 13:14:16 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 105

#
```

`/etc/nsswitch.conf`

```
# cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# An example Name Service Switch config file. This file should be
# sorted with the most-used services at the beginning.
#
# The entry '[NOTFOUND=return]' means that the search for an
# entry should stop if the search in the previous entry turned
# up nothing. Note that if the search failed due to some other reason
# (like no NIS server responding) then the search continues with the
# next entry.
#
# Valid entries include:
#
#   nisplus         Use NIS+ (NIS version 3)
#   nis         Use NIS (NIS version 2), also called YP
#   dns         Use DNS (Domain Name Service)
#   files           Use the local files
#   db          Use the local database (.db) files
#   compat          Use NIS on compat mode
#   hesiod          Use Hesiod for user lookups
#   [NOTFOUND=return]   Stop searching if not found so far
#

# To use db, put the "db" in front of "files" for entries you want to be
# looked up first in the databases
#
# Example:
#passwd:    db files nisplus nis
#shadow:    db files nisplus nis
#group:     db files nisplus nis

passwd:     files
shadow:     files
group:      files

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns

# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files     

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files

netgroup:   nisplus

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files nisplus
aliases:    files nisplus

#
```

Comment: Could you put the /etc/hosts content and the results of the dig commands:
`dig @10.52.223.41 test.XXX.local`
`dig @10.52.223.42 test.XXX.local`

Comment: @alexus No, Adrian Perez asked you to update your question by providing your `/etc/hosts` file content and some `dig` output !!! To help us debug

Comment: @alexus sorry.. it's my bad english i want you to paste the contents of the /etc/hosts to see the records there..
Launch the dig commands to see if the dns servers resolve right (paste the results..)

Comment: @alexus Can you also post the content of your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` ?

Comment: @user2196728 done

Comment: Are you using `Avahi` ? I would suggest to delete `[NOTFOUND=return]` or put it after `dns` for the `hosts:` line

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/76421/wget-cant-resolve-host/76720#76720

Answer (score 3):

If you have `mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]` in your `nsswitch.conf` this is certainly because you have the `Avahi` daemon running on your system.

`Avahi` uses multicast DNS for `.local` zone, that makes it incompatible with DNS that only supports unicast DNS for zone `.local`. (e.g Microsoft's DNS only supports Unicast DNS for the `.local` zone).

In such a network setup (where DNS only supports unicast for `.local` zone), `Avahi` recommands to not use `Avahi`.

However, they provide some workaround :

Remove `mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]` from `nsswitch.conf` to finally have something like this :

```
hosts: files dns mdns4
```

But their main advice is to setup `avahi-daemon.conf` like this to avoid multicast DNS for `.local` zone :

```
domain-name=.alocal
```

---

To solve your issue, either  :

- shutdown the `Avahi` daemon

OR

- Set up your `nsswitch.conf` accordingly to recommendations :

`hosts: files dns mdns4`

OR

- Set up your `avahi-daemon.conf` accordingly to recommendations :

`domain-name=.alocal`

---

Further reading :

- http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2011/09/fix-linux-dns-issues-with-local.html
- http://avahi.org/wiki/AvahiAndUnicastDotLocal

Comment: 1) Actually .41 and .42 are RHEL6 and not Microsoft. 2) after setting domain-name=.alocal `avahi-daemon` service won't even starts up anymore.

Comment: ok, so your RHEL6s does not seems to support multicast DNS for .local zone, just as Microsoft's ones. For 2) i admit i am not an Avahi expert, i've just read the doc. Have you read carefully my second link ? you could find interesting infos. I've updated my post to extend "my blaming" to not only Microsoft, but more generally the incompatibily between muticast/unicast DNS for .local zone

Comment: PS : for 2), if Avahi does not strart with `.alocal`, my guess is because this zone should exists on your DNS. Tou could try to create it first.

Comment: I have `XXX.local` zone, not `.alocal`.

Comment: I know, that is my i've suggested you to also create a `.alocal` zone to see if Avahi can start when you set it with `domain-name=.alocal `

Answer (score 2):

props to @guntbert

```
# service avahi-daemon stop
Shutting down Avahi daemon:                                [  OK  ]
# ping test.XXX.local
PING test.XXX.local (10.52.223.42) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from test.XXX.local (10.52.223.42): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=1.15 ms
^C
--- test.XXX.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 625ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.152/1.152/1.152/0.000 ms
# chkconfig avahi-daemon off
#
```

I *REALLY* wish to understand *WHY?* though...

Comment: This has to deal with unicast and multicast DNS. Here is the "why?" : http://www.lowlevelmanager.com/2011/09/fix-linux-dns-issues-with-local.html To resume, it seems you use Microsoft DNS and `.local` zones only support unicast DNS. Avahi provide multicast DNS

Comment: @user2196728 it's still unclear for me due to fact, that `/etc/nsswitch.conf` & `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` are identical between several machines, yet only one (at least so far) is experiencing this issue while others do not.

Comment: Are Avahi daemons running on your other machines ?

Comment: @user2196728 yes, it does. that's what really weird...

Comment: Take care that order is very important for the `hosts:` line in `nsswitch.conf` ! Are directive in the same order on your others machines ?

Comment: yes, all machines are the same (they were build same way, and running same way) i double check avahi _IS_ running and resolution is working.

Comment: Last question (to avois tchat) : are all machines use the same DNS server ?

Comment: @user2196728 yes, all of them are using same DNS server

Comment: So i am baffled ! But interesting. To investigate deeper, first, i would suggest to mark one of these answers as "answered" (if one of them have solved your initial issue), and second, open a new question to ask `Why DNS behaviour is different from one server to another ?` providing config files for both servers. I will do some tests in Lab

Answer (score 1):

Modify your nsswitch.conf. Change the line

`hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns`

to

`hosts:      files dns`

mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] affects to .local domains and doesn't allow to reach "dns" level. So i think that doing the above change, the resolution should work.

Comment: I have yet another Linux machine on same network using same DNS w/ same `nsswitch.conf` and yet everything is working.